# how to save text execution plan in a temporary table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to save the text execution plan in a temporary table so that i can do some analysis on the performance.
Please tell me how to do it.

I intend to find all the performance problems via a procedure.
Using MS-SQL Server 2008

Comment: What is your operating system and database engine?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use [SQL Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx) that gives you options to store the trace information into tables and analyze them at a later point.

BTW, you would need ALTER TRACE permissions on the database to be able to run the profiler.

Comment: I have not used much SQL Profiler, but does it displays the exact execution plan as SSMS does. As far as i know SQL Profiler will trace all the conenctions/request made to the server. It will be really helpful if i can save the text execution plan in a table! I dont know if there can be a exactly relevant alternative.

Comment: If you are interested in the number of reads/writes, cpu times etc., it will trace those details. But if you are looking for the index that was used/table scan details etc., it doesn't.

Comment: Exactly, i require the table scans, indexes and other details that an execution plan displays

Comment: Have you looked at the text output of the execution plan (by using SET SHOWPLAN_TEXT ON) to see if that can be stored in some structured format?

Comment: Vikdor, No offense!.. Please read my question once again :).. thats exactly what my question says!

Comment: sorry! only the "execution plan" thing went in :( Read your question thoroughly. would you mind just pasting a sample plan in text format (don't have access to an SQL server currently).